# The "how many pieces do you have buy on average" problem, a markov problem?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

I recently discovered a problem similar to this one in a book about Markov chains:

Assume you can buy $n-$ different set of cards in a store, but you do not know which one you'll buy: What is the average number of sets you have to buy until have all $n-$ sets together?

I was really puzzled how this problem can be viewed as a Markov chain? Does anybody have a hint how to solve these kind of problem with markov chains?

Comment: Yes the number of different sets one gets after one bought k sets is a Markov chain on {0,1,...,n} with transitions from k to k and from k to k+1 only.

Comment: This is, by the way, the Coupon Collector's Problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem